# nested git checkout on groovy script (jenkins' workflow)

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I'm dealing with jenkins' workflow. My project includes another big project that I'd like to use sparse checkout feature. I've found a couple of issues so far:

(1) I don't know how to clone a repo into a new directory

```
git url:'https://some.git.server/project.git', param1:'value1',...
```

(2) inside the above project perform a sparse checkout

I couldn't find any groovy syntax specification.

Below is the script version I want to do using groovy

```
git clone https://some.git.server/project.git
cd project/subdir
git init
git remote add -f origin https://some.git.server/another.project.git
echo Source/Base > .git\info\parse-checkout
echo Source/Core > .git\info\parse-checkout
git pull origin master 
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [SCMs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/) out  (Multiple SCMs tag), I'm afraid it will help you to answer your first question.

About the second question I cannot answer it, but you can dig around `checkout` tag, it's a generic SCM command, for instance:

```
checkout ([$class: '...', source: '...'])
```

You could find an exhaustive [list of workflow](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md) compatible commands.

Regards!

Comment: On workflow window: (1) check the _Snippet Generator_. (2) select _General SCM_ on _Sample Step_ select box. (3) set URL, credentials, and so on (4) add a _Sparse Checkout paths_ on _Additional Behaviours_